# jQuery removeClass does not actually remove class

Tags: jquery, live, addclass, removeclass

I have an anchor that triggers some events when it is clicked, and adds a new class and removes the old one, but when I click it again with the new class the original event is triggered again (like if the class was not removed at all). I tried the `.live()` function but didn't help (`toggleclass()` didn't work either).

Does anyone know what's going on on this one?

```
$('.no-cuenta').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.login-inputs').hide('drop', 1000, function(){
      $('.register-inputs').show('drop', 1000);
      $('.no-cuenta').empty().text('Ya tienes cuenta? Ingresa').addClass('si-cuenta').removeClass('no-cuenta');
    });
  });

  //Cargar la forma para loggearse
  $('.si-cuenta').live('click',function(d) {
    d.preventDefault();

    $('.register-inputs').hide('drop', 1000, function(){
      $('.login-inputs').show('drop', 1000);
      $('.si-cuenta').empty().text('No tienes cuenta? Registrate').addClass('no-cuenta').removeClass('si-cuenta');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the .on() method to bind the click event handlers to a delegate. This makes sure the handlers are bound to any elements with the indicated class, even if they are created later on.

Note that the following code makes the `body`element your delegate to handle these click events, you should use the closest common parent that makes sense as a 'manager' for these elements:

```
$("body").on('click', '.no-cuenta', function () {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.login-inputs').hide('drop', 1000, function(){
        $('.register-inputs').show('drop', 1000);
        $('.no-cuenta')
            .empty()
            .text('Ya tienes cuenta? Ingresa')
            .addClass('si-cuenta')
            .removeClass('no-cuenta');
    });
});
$("body").on('click', '.si-cuenta', function () {
    d.preventDefault();

    $('.register-inputs').hide('drop', 1000, function(){
        $('.login-inputs').show('drop', 1000);
        $('.si-cuenta')
            .empty()
            .text('No tienes cuenta? Registrate')
            .addClass('no-cuenta')
            .removeClass('si-cuenta');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line register the callback on all elements that have the class at time of execution, even if they change class later :

```
$('.no-cuenta').click(function(e) {
```

Use

```
$(document).on('click', '.no-cuenta',function(e) {
```